# implementation of CNOT gate using a Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-computing

I need to show that using following Hamiltonian (for a closed bipartite system), we are able to implement the Controlled-Not gate.
The Hamiltonian is :

=g/4 ( − z )⊗ ( − x)

Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there is a typo in your Hamiltonian. If the Hamiltonian is $\hat{H} = g/4 (I - \sigma_z) \otimes (I - \sigma_z) $, then by explicit calculation
$$ \hat{H} = g/4
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, with appropriate evolution time $t$ with respect to $g$, we have the unitary generated by the Hamiltonian
$$U = e^{-i \hat{H} t } = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is the CPHASE gate or called controlled-Z gate.

reference: [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa14/lectures/lecture5.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs191/fa14/lectures/lecture5.pdf)

CNOT gate can be related to CPHASE by conjugating Hadamard gate $H$ (Phase kickback trick), that is, $$CNOT=(I\otimes H) CPHASE (I\otimes H)$$

Comment: not sure whether the latex formula doesn't work